# scrollTo inner div only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scrollto

I have a page with two scroll bars. I am using the scrollTo jquery plugin to jump to other areas on the same page. The problem is I only want the inner div to scrollTo and the outer div to remain at the top of the screen.

[Development site link click here](http://www.aus-media.com/dev/site_BYJ/schedule-pricing/pricing.html)

This is the script

```
$(".jump > li").click(function() {
    var qu = $(this).attr("id");
    var an = "#" + qu.replace("q","a");

    // step 8
    $.scrollTo(an, {duration: 800, axis:"y"});
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$.scrollTo();` you want to call `$(outerDivSelector).scrollTo()` here, and you also need a `return false` to prevent the normal browser jumping to that location from the link's `href` property, like this:

```
$(".jump > li").click(function() {
  var qu = $(this).attr("id");
  var an = "#" + qu.replace("q","a");
  $(".scroller").scrollTo(an, {duration: 800, axis:"y"});
  return false; //prevent the default link behavior
});
```